# numpy boolean indexing confusion

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Hello could someone explain how is the following code working?
After importing the required libraries..

```
>>>features=np.random.rand(150,4)
>>>features= np.append(features,np.random.randint(3,size=(150,1)),axis=1)
>>>target=np.array([0,1,2])
>>>plt.scatter(features[target == 1,0], features[target == 1,1], marker='o', c='r')
```

I am getting a plot of 1st and 2nd  column of 'features' having 1 in the last column. But I am not able to understand how.

As far as I can understand 'target==1' creates a boolean array but how can it return values of the 1st and 2nd columns when there is no value representing 1 in those columns.

Does numpy indexing search values from all columns?

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a matrix and a vector:

```
A =np.array([[1,2,3],
    [4,5,6]])

b = np.array([0, 1, 2])
```

And you do the following:

```
A[b==1,2] # will return 6
```

This tells python you want the row index where `b==1` (ie `1`) and you want the column index of `2` in the matrix `A`.

Another example:

```
A[b==0,1] # will return 2
```

Similarly, in your example, you are finding scalar values.

Comment: yeah thanks, I later realized what mistake I was making